# Google tag manger for ios not loading container

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, google-tag-manager

I am trying to add google tag manager in my xcode project which will track firebase events in ios.
I've created a tag container and added in my project. (In Project directory > Supporting files)

[image]

in appdelegate file , code for opening the container:

```
[TAGContainerOpener openContainerWithId:@"GTM-TH3QM6P"   // Update with your Container ID.
                             tagManager:self.tagManager
                               openType:kTAGOpenTypePreferFresh
                                timeout:&timeout
                               notifier:self];
```

When I run , getting:

```
GoogleTagManager verbose: Loading default container from GTM-TH3QM6P
GoogleTagManager warning: Error reading resource from binary container file: Last tag: 116 should be 124
GoogleTagManager debug: Resource not on disk
GoogleTagManager verbose: scheduleTask: containerId=GTM-TH3QM6P delay=0.000000
GoogleTagManager warning: Error when loading resources from url: https://www.googletagmanager.com/r?id=GTM-TH3QM6P&v=i107577340 status code = 403
```

Whats the error here. Its saying: "Last tag: 116 should be 124" and https://www.googletagmanager.com/r?id=GTM-TH3QM6P&v=i107577340 link is not working, what should I change actually.
I have tried adding container binary as "GTM-XXXXXXX.json" also, but can't load that also.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: hi, anyone have any answer?

Comment: ok, previously  I manually added Googletag manager into the project. Now I have installed through pod and included GTM-XXXXXXX.json file inside container folder. I guess now its loading the container properly